# cannot reduce spacing between Android Action bar buttons

Tags: android

I am setting the action bar button style property in my styles, but in API 20, it has no affect:

```
<resources>

<!-- Base application theme. -->
<style name="AppTheme" parent="android:Theme.Holo.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/LoopActionBarStyle</item>
    <item name="android:buttonStyle">@style/LoopActionBarButtonStyle</item>
</style>

<style name="LoopActionBarButtonStyle" parent="@android:style/Widget.Holo.Light.ActionButton">
    <item name="android:padding">0dip</item>
    <item name="android:paddingLeft">0dip</item>
    <item name="android:paddingRight">0dip</item>
    <item name="android:minWidth">0dp</item>
</style>
```

I've read comments that for API 17 and below I need to handle it differently, I am testing this on API 20 so it shouldn't be an issue, right?
when I set the prview API to 19, it does work (the spacing goes away), so is there a new method needed for API 20?

Answer (score 0):

I was setting the `name="android:buttonStyle"` instead of `name="android:ActionButtonStyle"`